# Expressing the language of a grammar

Tags: grammar

How do I express the language accepted by a grammar into a set notation, i.e. the following grammar?

```
S → aSa|A
A → bAb|B
B → ccB|λ
```

Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion is to work inside out. Start with the language of `B` (which is any sentence containing an even number of `c`s.) (I can't write that in mathematical notation here; you need to use a site like [cs.se] or [math.se] where MathJax is enabled, *and* it would be useful to learn a little bit about how to use MathJax.)